# Multiple transactions to same document failure in flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am been trying to implement multiple transactions to the same document in flutter application which is using firestore as a its database, but it is crashing the application. The same thing when it was implemented in native apps of Xcode or android studio this issue didn't occur for even once.

Is there any guide how to make multiple transactions successful in flutter firestore.

For Instance, if more than 1 user from different devices is making the transaction to the same document at the same time, the transaction fails and the app crashes.

How could this be resolved?

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
      DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(docRef);
      if (postSnapshot.exists) {
        await tx.update(docRef, <String, dynamic>{'likes': postSnapshot.data['likes'] + 1});
       // print("transaction completed");
      }
    })
```

**ERROR LOGS**

> 2020-05-27 18:43:14.529 1022-1344/dev.jideguru.social_app_ui
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4 Process:
>   dev.jideguru.social_app_ui, PID: 1022 java.lang.RuntimeException: An
>   error occurred while executing doInBackground() at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) Caused by:
>   java.lang.AssertionError: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: A transaction
>   object cannot be used after its update callback has been invoked. at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Assert.fail(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:46)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Assert.hardAssert(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:31)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.ensureCommitNotCalled(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:246)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.lookup(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:81)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.getAsync(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:191)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:228)
>   at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:613)
>   at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:608)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)  2020-05-27 18:43:14.529
>   1022-1346/dev.jideguru.social_app_ui E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #6 Process: dev.jideguru.social_app_ui, PID: 1022
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) Caused by:
>   java.lang.AssertionError: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: A transaction
>   object cannot be used after its update callback has been invoked. at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Assert.fail(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:46)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Assert.hardAssert(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:31)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.ensureCommitNotCalled(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:246)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.lookup(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:81)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.getAsync(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:191)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:228)
>   at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:613)
>   at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:608)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

[Link To the Issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1969)

Comment: If the app crashes, you're probably doing something wrong.  Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, and provide details about the crash.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added the a link to this issue from GitHub. Please check that and guide me. This issue is being face by many other developers as well

Comment: The relevant code needs to appear in the question itself, not a link, along with information about the crash, and your description about what it's actually supposed to do.

Comment: @DougStevenson added the code which runs successfully at a time, but if the same transaction is happening to the same document at same time from different device it crashes the application, the link I shared is of GitHub related to the flutter  firestorm dependency which is open since February 2020, and not resolved yet

Comment: "the transaction fails and the app crashes" Please add the exact error message and stack trace to the question too.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the error log, please check

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: A transaction object cannot be used after its update callback has been invoked." It looks like the transaction is being used after it's been committed/canceled. I don't see anything in your code that's causing this, so might this be a problem in FlutterFire? Like: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1969

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes this is the problem with FlutterFire, it's the issue since February , 2020, I hope team at Firebase gets resolved it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: A transaction object cannot be used after its update callback has been invoked.

It looks like the transaction is being used after it's been committed/canceled.

This is a known issue in the FlutterFire library, as recorded in [this issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1969) on the open-source repo.

There is a workaround mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1969#issuecomment-616719132). So you can either try to apply that to your case, propose a PR that fixes the bug, or wait until somebody else fixes it.

Comment: Yo I've been having the same issues and am kinda freaking out after finding some flutterfire threads of other developers having the same issue for months now... Did you try this fix with .then() instead of async/await?

Comment: Just switched all my transactions to the .then() method. It did not make a difference for crashes.